# Is This Valid BNF Grammar?

Tags: bnf

I just wrote up some BNF and I'm a noobie at it, so I wanted to check with you guys if this is valid grammar, and if the input supplied can run?

BNF:

```
<expr> -> <id>  <id> + <id> +  | <id>  <id> + <id> - | <id>  <id> - <id> + | <id>  <id> - <id> -
<id> ->  A | B | C
```

My postfix input:

`A B + C -`

Would this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid separator between a symbol and an expression is `::=` and not `->`.
Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for details.

Anyway, a better grammar would look like this:

```
<expr> ::= <id> [ <id> [ <operator> ]? ]{2}
<operator> ::= '-' | '+'
<id> ::= [ '0' .. '9' | 'A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z' ]+
```

Comment: Would my current code work using `::=` though? I'm trying to find out if I have the right idea. I'm not really trying to make beautiful grammar at the moment.

Comment: I don't know. BNF is a standard, like when you define a protocol but used here for language grammars. What is the parser you're using?

Comment: I'm not using a parser. I'm actually learning about BNF at the moment and my professor is just having us write the grammar without testing it. The particular question I'm doing is "Write a grammar in BNF for postfix addition and subtraction
expressions involving only the variables A, B, and C.".

Comment: Then, there is no code that will "work" using `::=` or not, as there are no code. After defining the BNF grammar, you'll write code (creating simple [LL parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) for example).

Comment: How is there any way for me to know if my BNF is a valid answer to the assignments question then?

Comment: `BNF` is a grammar definition, so that's not testable code. That's only logic. Please read the wikipedia link I gave in my answer.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question, **yes** the grammar you given will match with your input, using the second OR.